# How to groupby year and month for netCDF file in python

Tags: python, group-by, netcdf

So I have a nc file, which has the following variables.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

[enter image description here][1]

My aim is to get the average value of 'mslp' that groupby both month and year.

I tried the following codes:

```
da.groupby('time').mean()
```

and also

```
 da.groupby('time').mean('mslp')
```

However, error occurred.

```
ValueError: cannot reduce over dimensions ['mslp']. expected either '...' to reduce over all dimensions or one or more of Frozen(SortedKeysDict({'lat': 17, 'lon': 1})).
```

What is the solution for this? Would be so grateful if you can provide me the solution.

[image: 1]

Comment: Your error message tells you what you should send to mean: "ValueError: cannot reduce over dimensions ['mslp']. expected either '...' to reduce over all dimensions or one or more of Frozen(SortedKeysDict({'lat': 17, 'lon': 1}))."

Comment: Yes, but I am fresh to python and don't know how to reduce all the dimensions, would be grateful if you could provide me examples on that.. Thanks!

Comment: If you are fresh to python it is best to read user guides and tutorials. Xarray provides excellent documentation on how to use the mean method